# str_replace_all not working for "\n+" in R

Tags: r, stringr

I have some variable values that I'd like to update with str_replace and str_replace_all. I would love to know why the functions aren't working when "\n" is part of a pattern of characters, e.g., "\n+\n".

str_replace( "Example\nof\n+\nmy\nProblem", "\n+\n", "")

I'd like this to produce "Example\nofmy\nProblem".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add \\ in front of the plus sign.  e.g.:

```
str_replace( "Example\nof\n+\nmy\nProblem", "\n\\+\n", "")
```

Comment: Would have expected need for some extra \'s for the cr's unless fixed = TRUE

Comment: @42- don't think they're necessary - `gsub("\n", "", "1\n2\n3\n")` works too.

Comment: Any idea why it works? Thought this would need tripled '\'.

Comment: @thelatemail, thank you! Can either of you explain why your solutions work? They both work, but I don't understand why.